# Как выбрать данные из базы данных

Tags: база-данных, mysql, запрос, выборка

Есть таблица ввида

```
product_id | filter_id
1          | 1
1          | 2
2          | 1
3          | 1
4          | 4
4          | 2
4          | 1
```

В колонке product_id хранятся id товаров, а в filter_id id фильтра для товара.
Я не могу понять как можно вытянуть только те id, товара которые содержат несколько нужных айди фильтра

например, мне нужно получить все товары которые имеют фильтр с айди 1 и 2, а это товар с айди 1 и 4

Подскажите как это можно сделать одним запросом, или хотя бы натолкните куда копать.

Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Попробуйте использовать оператор IN.

Comment: @NekoSin4eG, IN работает по принципу OR, а мне надо чтоб было AND

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Спасибо за ответ, я нашел способ сделать так как надо

```
SELECT DISTINCT * FROM product_filter WHERE filter_id = 1 AND product_id IN (SELECT product_id  FROM product_filter WHERE filter_id = 2)
```

Answer (score 5):

```
SELECT DISTINCT product_id
  FROM table_name
  WHERE filter_id IN (1, 2)
```

Comment: спасибо за Ваш ответ, но под данный запрос попадут и товар 2 и товар 3, потому что у них есть filter_id 1, а мне нужно выбрать только те у которых есть и фильтр 1 и фильтр 2

Comment: В таком случае в WHERE нужно изменить условие:
WHERE filter_id = 1 AND filter_id = 2

Comment: @andreyqin, так тоже не получается, это я попробовал в первую очередь. Тут нужен какой-то более сложный запрос, но я пока не пойму какой.